Is a staked u-joint the same as a tack welded u-joint?
What does it mean for u-joint caps to be staked in place? Is that the same thing as an array of tack welds going around the u-joint cap or is this some other kind of retention design?

U-joints that are designed to be easily replaced have some kid of internal circlip holding the u-joint caps in place.

A staked u-joint has some of the metal of the joint peened over to hold the caps in place like in this photo -

It is still possible to replace these u-joints.  If you search on YouTube for staked ujoint you will find examples of mechanics doing this.

Very interesting, I need to understand the "some of the metal" part, like which part's metal is being peened over exactly? So looking at that bottom staked photo the outermost circle is the shaft or yoke of the U-joint. Imagine this being a stack of stairs where the shaft/yoke is the 3rd step. The inner circle is the u-joint cap, or the 1st step. What is the part in-between, the 2nd step, which is being peened over--is that a circlip or its part of the shaft/yoke?

Ah actually I just clicked the photo link I just noticed, the fella does a great step by step walkthrough That image you grabbed above is the one with the caption Staked Joint. Notice the dimpled steel to be cut out.. That's a good synonym to pull into this question dimpled/peened. So the 2nd step I was curious about I can now see is the shaft from the photo captioned Still burs in there, clean em up. This is curious that the shaft has a groove for a circlip but they dimpled the shaft over instead. Must be cheaper bill of materials I suppose for the manufacturer.

The first two steps going down are the yoke, with the second step having the staking.  The 3rd and 4th step are the cap.  This guy on YouTube replaces a staked u-joint, his replacement joint has clips that go on the opposite side of the caps to what I have usually seen - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o8TnofLf1mU

Ah so that fella has a hydraulic press which he uses to brute force push the caps through the stakings themselves, wow. In that first pressing the caps fracture and shatter and rip off and the cylinder half gets stuck with the trunnion in the yoke. I think his technique could be improved on to force push the caps just till the stakes are exposed followed by filing them down then press out the other half and repeat and free the trunnions.

I wonder how general the brute force technique works with respect to the condition of the caps. He did mention caps are a brittle hardened steel which should facilitate their fracturing into pieces to remove bit by bit. At the least the thin metal of the cap should deform around the stakes and expose the stakes on the opposite side to do the filing like I mentioned. I'll play with this approach; I'm researching dealing with my old drive shaft with a bad grease leaking u-joint that has a lot of play on it.
